# Make autorun Login Screen on a Flash Drive!

Tags: shell-script, usb-drive

I want every time I connect with the Flash Drive on a CLI Shell start my Shell Script with a Message who only runs in my Flash Drive!!

I want him to Work Like the `/etc/bash.bashrc` on Linux, when you have figlet package and make a Message to appear on the Screen, like Below:

```
# MAKE A LOGIN SCREEN
printf "=================================\n"
figlet -f standard "F4NT0 ARCH LINUX"
figlet -f  small "CLI Operational System"
printf "=================================\n"
```

Comment: Use custom udev rules.

Comment: I'm looking here, but do you know a good website of how to do it?

Comment: I try it but I would need to alterate the udev rules of all my computers, i need something to run on the flash drive in every computer without need to create a file with the rules on each computer